# access error in xlsx report from odoo

Tags: report, odoo, rules

The access rule in multi company. **The user's allowed company is 1 company.** 
Print custom report action, then error is:

```
Please contact your system administrator(  sale.order, Operation: read)
```

The report is xlsx report. The query is:

```
    def _get_values(self, date_from, date_to, company_id):
     self.env.cr.execute("""(
        Select
            //some field
                                    FROM ( sale_order s
                                          join sale_order_line l on (l.order_id=s.id)
                                          join res_partner partner on s.partner_id = partner.id
                                            left join product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id)
                                            left join product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id)
                                            left join stock_warehouse w on (w.id=s.warehouse_id)

                                        )
                                    WHERE s.date_order >= '%s' AND s.date_order < '%s' AND s.company_id IN %s
                                    GROUP BY fields
                                    ORDER BY s.date_order) """
                                        % (date_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), date_to.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), tuple( company_id)))
return self.env.cr.fetchall()
```

How to fix this access error. Help, I need any solution and advice. Thanks for your help!

Additional note:

```
 def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, lines):
    lines = self._get_values(date_from, date_to, aa)
    for line in lines:
         sheet.write(rowx, 1, line[0], format_datetime)
         // some write sheet ...
```

and print button action in call xlsx report.
The code is:

```
@api.multi
    def export_xls(self):
        datas = {'date_from': self.date_from,
                 'date_to': self.date_to}
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
                'report_name': 'sale_report.xlsx',
                'datas': datas,
                'name': _('Sales report excel')
                }
```

Comment: it works just fine with **many companies**

Comment: That's a mix of python and sql. Could you please share the code, which is raising the error and not a bad pseudo-mix-code?

Comment: Post the stacktrace and the implementation of `_get_values`